# Difference between GraalVM and Jvm-Hotspot

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, graalvm

Can someone explain the differences between GraalVM and Jvm-Hotspot, and how GraalVM is related to OpenJDK's HotSpot.

Comment: quick link:
https://blog.frankel.ch/first-impressions-graalvm/

Answer (score 20):

In that context you could think of GraalVM as a modified/improved HotSpot JVM [very loosely: OpenJDK's HotSpot + the Graal JIT Compiler (replacing the one from HotSpot) + the ability to run other languages (JS, Ruby, R, Python, etc.) + ability to AOT compile Java 
 + additional bundled tools, etc.]

Answer (score 5):

GraalVM is a JVM with multiple change:

- the graal compiler. It is intended to replace the C2 compiler (server mode) in front of HotSpot.
- Truffle a library that you can implements to make JVM polyglot ( there already a number of language that are supported like js, R, Ruby...)

The graal project also have a Substrate VM which is a framework to build native artifact from Java.

Answer (score 5):

Detailed information about how Graalvm performs better than standard Hotspot and how to use it: https://www.baeldung.com/graal-java-jit-compiler

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the C2 compiler is replaced with the Graal compiler.

> GraalVM is a full-scale JDK distribution that can make Java
> applications run faster with a new advanced just-in-time compiler
> (Graal). As a platform it uses the Java HotSpot VM, so all tools and
> libraries that work on OpenJDK, work the same way on GraalVM JDK. In
> this context, GraalVM replaces the last-tier optimizing compiler in
> the JVM (C2) with the Graal compiler. This compiler is the outcome of
> 10+ years of research at Oracle Labs and includes several new
> optimizations, such as advanced inlining, partial escape analysis,
> code duplication, and speculative optimizations. GraalVM is itself
> written in Java, rather than C/C++, which simplifies maintenance and
> helps us develop and deliver new optimizations much faster.
>
> Several companies, such as Oracle Cloud, Twitter, and Facebook are
> running large-scale Java applications on GraalVM JDK to increase
> performance, reduce resource usage, and lower deployment costs.
> GraalVM JDK can simply be used as a drop-in replacement for other JDKs
> — see how to get started.

[Reference](https://www.graalvm.org/why-graalvm/)